# Error stating class must implement a method that is already there

Tags: java, android

I have looked at the other threads, and they haven't worked for me at all yet.

I am new to Java and Android Development. I am trying to make a login for my Android app, so I was trying to follow a tutorial online and then tweak it the way I would like it to be. So I am getting errors throughout the entire project, and they are all about the same thing. On the site it says it is working fine, so I don't know what I am doing.

So, now for the errors!

- Class 'NetCheck' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(params...)' in 'AsyncTask'

@Override in Netcheck Class (all of them except the one for onPreExecute) gives this error: Method does not override method in super class

Class 'ProcessRegister' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(params....) in 'AsyncTask'

@Overide in ProcessRegister class gives error: Method does not override method in super class. All @overrides gives error besides onPreExecute.

After looking at the other posts, it said to make sure the methods are public or protected. Which they are, and the other said to check spelling. Everything looks good to me though, unless I am missing something. Can someone please give me some help! Thanks!!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.drm.ProcessedData;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import wishlist.com.gimme.library.UserFunctions;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class PasswordReset extends Activity {

private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

EditText email;
TextView alert;
Button resetpass;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.passwordreset);

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktolog);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }

    });

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.forpas);
    alert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alert);
    resetpass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respass);
    resetpass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            NetAsync(view);

        }

    });}

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask

{
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(PasswordReset.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessRegister().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            alert.setText("Error in Network Connection");
        }
    }
}

protected class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String forgotpassword;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        forgotpassword = email.getText().toString();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PasswordReset.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.forPass(forgotpassword);
        return json;

    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... args) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        /**
         * Checks if the Password Change Process is sucesss
         **/
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                alert.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    alert.setText("A recovery email is sent to you, see it for more details.");

                }
                else if (Integer.parseInt(red) == 2)
                {    pDialog.dismiss();
                    alert.setText("Your email does not exist in our database.");
                }
                else {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    alert.setText("Error occured in changing Password");
                }

                }}
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `AsyncTask` need to look like this, depends what are you need or doing: `AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>`

Comment: If you have a different question, then ask a new question. Don't try to morph one question into another.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the JavaDocs for `AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), you will see it denoted as:

```
android.os.AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

and you will see the sample `DownloadFilesTask` declared as:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
```

Your implementations lack the data types for the generics.

To that end, change:

```
private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask
```

to:

```
private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
```

as `doInBackground()` has a `String...` parameter (first data type), is not calling `publishProgress()` (second data type `Void`, since we aren't using it), and is returning a `Boolean` (third data type).

Similarly, change:

```
protected class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask
```

to:

```
protected class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>
```

The `Integer` is because you are implementing `onProgressUpdate()` as taking an `Integer`, though you do not seem to be using it.

Comment: I looked at the java docs and saw that but wasn't sure was it was. Thanks for the detailed description, that really helps a lot and I actually understand it!

I am getting an error on a different java file, 

     String email;
     DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
     HashMap user = new HashMap();
     user = db.getUserDetails();

     email = user.get("email");

I am getting the error: Incompatible Types
Required: Java.Lang.String
Found: Java.Lang.Object/

Email is a string, so why is it finding object?